# ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE in PostgreSQL 12

Tags: postgresql, indexing, expression

I want to create an expression index, but when I create the index, the following message is output:

```
CREATE INDEX member_lastactivity_idx ON adempiere.member USING btree (member_id, referredby, ((lastactivity::date)>CURRENT_DATE-interval'60 days'));
```

Comment: Immutable functions are required in an index which means that their results must always be the same. This is not the case for CURRENT_DATE. So the error massage.

Comment: The index definition depends on the query you are trying to improve. If it's something like `where member_id = .. and referredby = .. and lastactivity > ...` then just include `lastactivity` in the index.